# is it possible to parse the jwt token with out key in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, jwt

When I use this code to parse the jwt token in Python 3.10(pyjwt==2.8.0):

```
import jwt

if __name__ == '__main__':
    access_token = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJyb2xlIjoiSW5kaXZpZHVhbCIsInVzZXJJZCI6Ikp5UHZaczhTVUVwYkZXQkpsLzRwK2RBclRhRE5Tc28wVzZaVTVXN2k1L1E9IiwiZW1haWwiOiJGU3A2SmNvakRsd2xnVnZDa2YzOUxKVDN0bVhRRVF3TGdwSXRTSVkzNitwVmJyRlR5L0xzYkM2NFZnTVQzdkVXMDBZNzBkSjIvQlJ1TC9SL05QQWt5UT09IiwibmJmIjoxNjk5NDI5ODg4LCJleHAiOjE2OTk0MzU4ODgsImlhdCI6MTY5OTQyOTg4OH0.ujpKdHcdN2R2-6Bw9aR1d0RjCDuJLMUogge4FGb0F01oMKpeP4EM4FVbOuOZj0KwtSOl2gsb5yoBt0ooqXz8GA"
    parsed_token = jwt.decode(jwt=access_token, key='', verify=False, algorithms=['HS512'])
    exp = parsed_token["exp"]
```

shows error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dolphin/Applications/PyCharm Community.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1500, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/Users/dolphin/Applications/PyCharm Community.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/Users/dolphin/source/visa/test/test_jwt_parse.py", line 5, in <module>
    parsed_token = jwt.decode(jwt=access_token, key='', verify=False, algorithms=['HS512'])
  File "/Users/dolphin/source/visa/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jwt/api_jwt.py", line 210, in decode
    decoded = self.decode_complete(
  File "/Users/dolphin/source/visa/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jwt/api_jwt.py", line 151, in decode_complete
    decoded = api_jws.decode_complete(
  File "/Users/dolphin/source/visa/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jwt/api_jws.py", line 209, in decode_complete
    self._verify_signature(signing_input, header, signature, key, algorithms)
  File "/Users/dolphin/source/visa/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jwt/api_jws.py", line 310, in _verify_signature
    raise InvalidSignatureError("Signature verification failed")
jwt.exceptions.InvalidSignatureError: Signature verification failed
python-BaseException
```

I have already specify the verify with false, still could not parse the jwt token. what should I do to fixed this issue? is it possible to parse the token without signature or secret? I have read the usage example https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html but did not found the demo without secret.

Comment: According to the documentation that you linked it is: `jwt.decode(encoded, options={"verify_signature": False})`

Comment: `verify=False` was valid in PyJWT < 2.0